# Running ssh git@github.com gives my username and one of my repositories

Tags: git, github, ssh-keygen

When trying to access one of my repositories I suddenly received the message;

```
ERROR: Permission to REPOSITORY_A denied to deploy key
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

after some searching, I ran `ssh git@github.com` and this gave the message

```
Hi USERNAME/REPOSITORY_B! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Shared connection to github.com closed.
```

and I believe this is only supposed to show your username and not a repository too. I'm assuming this is the cause I can't access my initial repository.

Now I have tried regenerating my ssh keys and adding them to my Github account and this did solve the problem. (I.e. running `ssh git@github.com` gave just the username and I could again access my repository A.) However, after restarting my terminal I am back to square one.

I haven't been able to find anyone with the same issue (I may well not be asking the right questions when googling) so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that for any reason your local ssh agent did not used a github known ssh key.
That explain why you could not read from your github repository and why regenerating a ssh key pair and add it again in your account solved your access problem.

Now when doing

```
ssh git@github.com
```

You are basically trying to open an ssh tunnel to the machine at github.com with user git. It is something you are forbidden to do but as git know your ssh key, they are able to print back your username saying that you are authenticated but you can't open a ssh shell.
It's a totally different thing than using a ssl tunnel to read/write in your repo using git CLI.

As for why they prompted back a /repoName after your username is probably an account configuration error or a github bug.